# How can I start a specific program upon RDP connection via Guacamole?

Tags: javascript, guacamole

I'm using the guacamole-common-js JavaScript library to connect to servers via my webclient. This works like a charm.
However - I can't get the initial-program parameter (as specified in the documentation: https://guacamole.apache.org/doc/gug/configuring-guacamole.html#session-settings) to force the server to start a specific program upon RDP-connection.
I add the argument like all others via the JSON-structure:

```
{
     "hostname": "some-address",
     "port": "some-port",
     "domain": "",
     "username": "xxxxx",
     "password": "xxxxxx",
     "security": "any",
     "ignore-cert": "true",
     "initial-program" : "[Full path to .exe application]",
     "enable-wallpaper" : "false",
     "enable-font-smoothing" : "true"
   }
```

Attributes like "enable-wallpaper" etc. works perfect. But the "initial-program" doesn't seem to work.

I also tried it through Guacamoles' own webportal. Here you can specify the initial program via a textbox:

[image]

This doesn't work either.

Am I using the attribute wrong? Or are there any specific requirements for the server to be able to use the initial-program attribute? I'm having a hard time finding any concrete examples, so I'm hoping someone can help me out.

Thanks a lot.